# PHP substr from a character

Tags: php, substr

I want to know what I am doing wrong in this code..

I am trying to generate a menu from the database but I have a problem. Some links are normal like "index.php" but some look like "browse.php|some.php|other.php" in the database.. I want to filter that and return all the normal values like "index.php" and where the "weird links" appear, just cut anything beyond the "|" character and become "browse.php". Right now, with the code I am using, index.php doesn't appear anymore but the weird links problem is solved.. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for any suggestion..

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE `Parent` = '0' AND Type LIKE 'top' ORDER BY `Order` ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: Query Failed! " .mysql_error());
    $output = "<ul>";
    while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $output .= "<li class='menu_top' id='".$rs['ID']."'><a href='".substr($rs['Link'], 0, strpos($rs['Link'], '|'))."'>".$rs['Name']."</a></li>";
        //$output .= "<li class='menu_top' id='".$rs['ID']."'><a href='".$rs['Link']."'>".$rs['Name']."</a></li>";
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE `Parent` = '".$rs['ID']."' ORDER BY `Order` ASC";
        $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die ("Error: Query Failed! " .mysql_error());
        if (mysql_num_rows($result2) != 0) {
          $output .= "<ul class='menu_sub' id='".$rs['ID']."'>";
          while ($rs2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
             $output .= "<li><a href='".$rs2['Link']."'>".$rs2['Name']."</a></li>";
          }
          $output .= "</ul>";
       }
    }
    $output .="</ul>";
    echo $output;
```

Comment: Explode the link string on '|', then use the 0th element of the resulting array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regullar expression `\|.*$` to remove everything after first `|`

Example code using preg_replace

```
// returns only first link before |
preg_replace('/\|.*$/','',$link);
```

Just use this code where you need to put link and you are fine if link is only `index.php` or `index.php|some.php` etc...

Answer (score 1):

This

```
strpos($rs['Link'], '|')
```

is returning false when the link is like 'index.php', so you are doing:

```
substr($string, 0, false);
```

Comment: Thank you, I used preg_replace, easier for a noob like me :)